# Same code rake task does nothing cosole succeeds

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rake-task

I was trying to do the simple task of adding states to a country in my new project.

I added a rake task so that the rest of my team can just run it and they are good to go and same for the production.

```
task :add_canada_states => :environment do
    puts "Finding Canada"
    canada = Country.find_by_name("Canada")
    if canada.present?
      puts "Found canada"
      canada_states_hash = [
        {name: "Ontario", code: "ON"},
        {name: "Quebec", code: "QC"},
        {name: "Nunavut", code: "NU"},
        {name: "Northwest Territories", code: "NWT"},
        {name: "Nova Scotia", code: "NS"},
        {name: "New Brunswick", code: "NB"},
        {name: "Manitoba", code: "MB"},
        {name: "British Columbia", code: "BC"},
        {name: "Prince Edward Island", code: "PE"},
        {name: "Saskatchewan", code: "SK"},
        {name: "Yukon", code: "YT"},
        {name: "Alberta", code: "AB"},
        {name: "Newfoundland and Labrador", code: "NL"}
      ]

      canada.states.create(canada_states_hash)
    else
      puts "Countries are not there"
    end

  end
```

After running the task locally the output was

```
Finding Canada
Found canada
```

Which was the expected, I double checked the database and found the records.

I did the same on the production server (heroku)

It printed the same output

```
Finding Canada
Found canada
```

After checking the database for the records, I found they were not added!

I copied the code and pasted it in the heroku rails console

And it added the data.

This is a very weird behaviour. What am I missing?

Comment: most likely an a environment flag missed but check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25282372/3109182) for details.

Comment: it has the same environment as my production app. so how is that possible?

Comment: how did you run the rake task? it's very unlikely that this does not work as expected since heroku replaces your database configuration, so you can't write to anything but the production db.

Comment: heroku run rake fixes:add_canada_states

Comment: Use create! just to make sure you're not running into validation errors even if its working in console, this way you can isolate the problem

Answer (score 1):

You used `canada.states.create`, the active record `create` has a soft fail, which means it returns false when it fails, and carries on.
 when running rake tasks you should use the `create!` with a bang `(!)` which fails by throwing an error, this way you would know when and why the error happened, so replace that line with

```
canada.states.create!(canada_states_hash)
```

Comment: Please read the question one more time. I took the code and pasted it in the console and it worked perfectly.

Comment: you mean it didn't throw an error, that's what `create` does, it doesn't stop when it fails, i said run it again but with a bang and see if it still works or not